# Maclaurin Series Question: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I obtain the Maclaurin series representation of:

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$$

I know I should use a well known Maclaurin Series and work my way back to the representation of this problem, but not sure what to compare it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function is
$$
\frac{1}{2}x\left(1 + \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}
$$

You first find the Maclaurin series for
$$
f(x) = (1 + (x/2)^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  
$$
and then you multiply by $x/2$.
Use [the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) that 
$$
(1 + x)^{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{k}{n}x^n
$$
So
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{n}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n}.
$$
"All" that you have to do is to figure out what the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) are.
By definition
$$
\binom{-1/2}{n} = \frac{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-1)(-\frac{1}{2}-2)\cdots(-\frac{1}{2} - n +1)}{n!}.
$$
Maybe if you canculate the first, say, five terms you can see a pattern.
$$
\binom{-1/2}{0} = 1 \\
\binom{-1/2}{1} = -\frac{1}{2}\\
\binom{-1/2}{2} = \frac{(-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})}{2!}
$$
Try to work out some more yourself.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @BillyThompson: No problem. Glad to help.